# How to configure SSL with commons-httpclient-4.0.3

Tags: apache-commons-httpclient

I'm unable to find any documentation on Apache commons-httpclient version 4.0.3. I'm deploying something in someone else's JVM and I'm stuck with the versions of libraries that they provide.

In particular, I need to configure SSL for httpclient. Does anyone know how to do this or where I can find some decent documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Found an example in their svn repository:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.0.3/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java